# Flutter - DropdownButton selectedValue is returning null in controller.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, return-value, getter

I have a dropdownButton of states and when the value is selected, the controller page is returning null. How can I get this value?

```
class StatesFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget with BaseField {
  late final MacroFieldDto _macroField;

  StatesFieldWidget({
    required MacroFieldDto macroField,
    required double fontSize,
    done = false
  }) : super(key: Key(macroField.uiCode)) {
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
    _macroField = macroField;
  }

  @override
  _StatesFieldWidgetState createState() {
    return _StatesFieldWidgetState();
  }

  @override
  MacroFieldDto? get value {
    return _macroField;
  }

  @override
  bool get valid {
    return value!.valid;
  }
}

class _StatesFieldWidgetState extends State<StatesFieldWidget> {
 
  
  String? selectedValue;
  String get value {
  
   
      if(selectedValue == null){
       log(selectedValue.toString());
          return "NU";
      } else{
       log(selectedValue.toString());
        return selectedValue.toString();
        
      }

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FieldContainerWidget.fieldContainer(
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
        //padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5, left: 5),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedValue,
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_downward,
            key: Key('btn_expand_states'),
          ),
          iconSize: 24,
          elevation: 16,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black87,
            fontSize: widget.fontSize,
          ),
          underline: Container(
            height: 0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) async {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = newValue;
            });
             // log(selectedValue.toString());
          },

          items: states().map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // TODO: verify behaviour for other languages;
  List<String> states() {
    final states = <String>[];
    states.add("AC");
    states.add("AL");
    states.add("AP");
    states.add("AM");
    states.add("BA");
    states.add("CE");
    states.add("DF");
    states.add("ES");
    states.add("GO");
    states.add("MA");
    states.add("MT");
    states.add("MS");
    states.add("MG");
    states.add("PA");
    states.add("PB");
    states.add("PR");
    states.add("PE");
    states.add("PI");
    states.add("RJ");
    states.add("RN");
    states.add("RS");
    states.add("RO");
    states.add("RR");
    states.add("SC");
    states.add("SP");
    states.add("SE");
    states.add("TO");

    return states;
  }


 
  

}
```

The controller.dart

```
class MessageSendController = _MessageSendControllerBase with _$MessageSendController;

abstract class _MessageSendControllerBase with Store {
  final txtSearchCtl = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GlobalKey<SendMessageAnimationTabletWidgetState>? sendAnimationTabletState;
  GlobalKey<SendMessageAnimationPhoneWidgetState>? sendAnimationPhoneState;

  final OdometerService _odometerService = IoC.get<OdometerService>()!;
  final AuthStatusService _authStatusService = IoC.get<AuthStatusService>()!;
  final MessageListController _messageListController = IoC.get<MessageListController>()!;

  String _odometerValue = '';
  String _driverIdValue = '';
  final MessageService _messageService = MessageService();
  bool? isMessageFromOperationCycle = false;
  bool isModalMessageOpen = false;

  @observable
  List<Macro> macros = [];

  @observable
  Macro selectedMacro = Macro();

  @observable
  List<BaseField> baseFields = [];

  @observable
  Widget? selectedMacroContainer;

  @observable
  bool isVisibleBtnImportant = true;

  @observable
  bool isVisibleBtnNormal = true;

  @action
  Future loadFields() async {
    double fontSize = _fontSize;
    baseFields = [];

    List<Row> rows = [];
    List<Widget> actualRow = [];
    int columnsCount = 0;

    for (var macroField in selectedMacro.fields) {
      if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.lineBreak || columnsCount >= 38) {
        rows.add(Row(children: actualRow));
        actualRow = [];
        columnsCount = 0;
        continue;
      }

      columnsCount += macroField.size!;
      actualRow.add(_getFieldWidget(macroField, fontSize));

      if (selectedMacro.fields.length > 15) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
      }
    }

    rows.add(Row(children: actualRow));

    selectedMacroContainer = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: rows,
    );
  }

  @action
  loadData() async {
    isModalMessageOpen = true;
    formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    await treatLoadFields();
  }

  Future treatLoadFields() async {
    if (selectedMacro.formNumber >= 0) {
      await loadFields();

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

      if (selectedMacro.formNumber > 0) {
        txtSearchCtl.text = "Formulário ${selectedMacro.formNumber.toString()}";
      } else {
        txtSearchCtl.text = "lbl_free_text".translate;
      }
    }
  }

  @action
  Future getHodometerAndDriverId(List<Macro> macroList) async {
    if (macroList.any((element) => element.fields.any((c) => c.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.odometerAutomatic))) {
      _odometerValue = await _getOdometer();
    }

    if (macroList.any((element) => element.fields.any((c) => c.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.driverId))) {
      _driverIdValue = await _getDriverId();
    }
  }

  @action
  String formatMacroName(Macro macro) {
    if (selectedMacro.formNumber < 0) return "";

    if (macro.formNumber == selectedMacro.formNumber) return "";

    if (macro.formNumber > 0) {
      return "Formulário ${macro.formNumber}";
    } else {
      return "Texto Livre";
    }
  }

  @action
  List<String>? getMacroNumberList() {
    if (macros.isEmpty) return null;
    List<String> list = [];
    for (var f in macros) {
      list.add(f.formNumber.toString());
    }

    return list;
  }

  @action
  Macro getMacroByFormNumber(int formNumber) {
    return macros.firstWhere((m) => m.formNumber == formNumber);
  }

  @action
  clearFormFields(BuildContext context) {
    Dialogterminalmovel.showConfirm(
      context: context,
      content: 'msg095'.translate,
      callbackYes: () {
        loadFields();
      },
    );
  }

  @action
  void macroNameChange(String newValue) {
    int? macroNumber = int.tryParse(newValue);

    Macro macro;

    if (macroNumber != null) {
      macro = macros.where((m) => m.formNumber == macroNumber).first;
    } else {
      macro = macros.where((m) => m.formNumber == 0).first;
    }

    selectedMacro = macro;
    loadFields();
  }

  @action
  Future<Message?> sendNormal(BuildContext context) async {
    return await _send(MessageTypePriority.normal, context, 0);
  }

  @action
  Future<Message?> sendImportant(BuildContext context) async {
    return await _send(MessageTypePriority.important, context, 0);
  }

  @action
  Future<Message?> sendNormalReply(BuildContext context, Message messageReply) async {
    return await _send(MessageTypePriority.normal, context, messageReply.messageUccId);
  }

  @action
  Future<Message?> sendImportantReply(BuildContext context, Message messageReply) async {
    return await _send(MessageTypePriority.important, context, messageReply.messageUccId);
  }

  Future<Message?> _send(int priority, BuildContext context, int? idMessageReply) async {
    try {
      isVisibleBtnImportant = false;
      isVisibleBtnNormal = false;

      if (formKey.currentState!.validate() == false) {
        isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
        isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
        return null;
      }

      final fields = baseFields.map((f) => f.value).whereNotNull().toList();
      //log(fields[1].value.toString());
      // final fieldz = fields.map((e) => e).toString();

      Message sendMessage;
      if (idMessageReply != null && idMessageReply > 0) {
        sendMessage = Message.send(
          fields: fields,
          priority: priority,
          macro: selectedMacro,
          idMessageReply: idMessageReply,
        );
      } else {
        sendMessage = Message.send(
          fields: fields,
          priority: priority,
          macro: selectedMacro,
        );
      }

      if (sendMessage.body == "_" && sendMessage.formNumber == 0) {
        Dialogterminalmovel.showOk(
          context: context,
          content: 'msg098'.translate,
          callback: () {
            isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
            isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
          },
        );
        return null;
      }
      if (sendMessage.body == "_" && sendMessage.formNumber > 0) {
          Dialogterminalmovel.showOk(
            context: context,
            content: 'null',
            callback: () {
              isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
              isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
            },
          );
          return null;
        }

      if (isMessageFromOperationCycle != true) {
        bool result = await _messageService.sendMessage(sendMessage);

        if (!result) {
          Dialogterminalmovel.showOk(
            context: context,
            content: 'msg002'.translate,
            callback: () {
              isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
              isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
            },
          );
          return null;
        }
      }

      await _messageListController.refresh(0);
      await _messageListController.refresh(1);

      if (DeviceType.get().isTablet!) {
        await sendAnimationTabletState!.currentState!.run();
      } else {
        await sendAnimationPhoneState!.currentState!.run();
      }

      isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
      isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
      isModalMessageOpen = false;

      return sendMessage;
    } catch (e) {
      isVisibleBtnImportant = true;
      isVisibleBtnNormal = true;
      return null;
    }
  }

  _getFieldWidget(MacroFieldDto macroField, double fontSize) {
    Widget? fieldWidget = Column();

    dynamic field;

    try {
      if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.alphabetical) {
        field = AlphabeticalFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.alphanumeric) {
        field = AlphanumericFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.zipCode) {
        field = ZipCodeFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.cpf) {
        field = CpfFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.date) {
        field = DateFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.dateComplete) {
        field = DateCompleteFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.daysOfWeek) {
        field = DaysOfWeekFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.states) {
        field = StatesFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.rangeOfIntegers) {
        field = RangeOfIntegersFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.intWithSignal) {
        field = IntWithSignalFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.intComplete) {
        field = IntCompleteFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.intWithoutSignal) {
        field = IntWithoutSignalFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.list) {
        field = ListFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.free) {
        field = FreeFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.month) {
        field = MonthFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.currency) {
        field = CurrencyFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.real) {
        field = RealFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.label) {
        field = LabelFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.password) {
        field = PasswordFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.yesNo) {
        field = YesNoFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.phone) {
        field = PhoneFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.phoneWithDDD) {
        field = PhoneWithDDDFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.time12H) {
        field = Time12hFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.time24H) {
        field = Time24hFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.odometerAutomatic) {
        macroField.value = _odometerValue;
        field = OdometerFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.driverId) {
        macroField.value = _driverIdValue;
        field = DriverIdFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.freeText) {
        field = FreeTextFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      } else if (macroField.macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.hourOfMessage) {
        var dateTime = DateTime.now().timeStamp.toString();
        macroField.value = dateTime;
        field = HourOfMessageFieldWidget(macroField: macroField, fontSize: fontSize);
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      field = const Text("");
    }
//log(field.toString());
    fieldWidget = field;
    baseFields.add(field);

    return fieldWidget;
  }

  _getOdometer() async {
    final odometer = await _odometerService.syncData();
    final odometerValue = odometer!.odometer.toStringAsFixed(2);
    return odometerValue;
  }

  _getDriverId() async {
    final authStatus = await _authStatusService.syncData();
    final driverId = authStatus != null && authStatus.driverId > 0 ? authStatus.driverId.toString() : '';
    return driverId;
  }

  double get _fontSize => DeviceType.get().isTablet! ? 30 : 14;
}
```

The function String get value doesn't work and the logs don't show up. And the fields is returning null. I wonder if it is to format or to stringfy the fields, because .map() won't resolve it, since the result is coming as an Instance of StatesWidget.

Adding up files to point out where the value is being handle.
It was created a class MacroFieldDto to init the value.

```
abstract class MacroFieldDto {
  int? size;
  bool? isRequired;
  String? param;
  int? macroFieldType;

  String? value;

  List<String> notifications = <String>[];

  String get uiCode => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  MacroFieldDto({
    this.size,
    this.isRequired,
    this.param,
    this.macroFieldType,
  });

  void inputTextIsValid();
  void setValueFromUccFormat(String value) => this.value = value;

  String? get valueToUccFormat => value;
  String? get formatedValue => value;

  bool get valid {
    notifications = <String>[];

    if (macroFieldType == MacroFieldType.label) {
      inputTextIsValid();
      return notifications.isEmpty;
    }

    _treatRequireValueIsValid();

    if (value != null && value!.isNotEmpty) {
      inputTextIsValid();
      _validateSize();
    }

    return notifications.isEmpty;
  }

  _treatRequireValueIsValid() {
    if (isRequired! && (value == null || value!.isEmpty)) {
      notifications.add("msg004");
    }
  }

  _validateSize() {
    if (value!.length > size!) notifications.add("msg006");
  }
}
```

And in the statesFieldDto the input is validated:

```
class StatesFieldDto extends MacroFieldDto {
  final String regexValidation = r'^[A-Z]{2}$';

  StatesFieldDto({int? size, bool? isRequired})
      : super(size: size, isRequired: isRequired) {
    macroFieldType = MacroFieldType.states;
  }

  @override
  void inputTextIsValid() {
    final regex = RegExp(regexValidation);
    if (regex.hasMatch(value!) == false) notifications.add("msg006");
  }
  @override
  void setValueFromUccFormat(String value) {
      this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Drop-down on changed is marked as async. Please remove it. Not sure if that's causing the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where `get value` is being used? The provided code just doesn't use it anywhere. The `DropdownButton` uses `selectedValue` for its value. Also, is the error something like this `Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null`?

Comment: @lepsch it's true the value is being held in 2 more pages. I'll provide them in the question above. And no the error is just returning " " due to the a null validation.

Comment: It looks like you should call the `widget.value!.setValueFromUccFormat` in `_StatesFieldWidgetState`, right inside the `setState`. Isn't it?

Comment: @lepsch it was a really good shot, but it is still getting null, when it passes on the model for the message:  
    if (macro.formNumber > 0) {
      subtype = MessageSubtype.form;
      formNumber = macro.formNumber;
      formGroupId = macro.formGroupId;
      formVersion = macro.formVersion;

      body = fields
          .where((f) =>
              f.macroFieldType != MacroFieldType.label &&
              f.macroFieldType != MacroFieldType.lineBreak)
          .map((f) => "_" + (f.valueToUccFormat ?? 'Null'))
          .join('');

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to set the value through `setState` (from the comments).
But it could be the case of setting through a validator as well.

```
onChanged: (salutation) =>
                  setState(() => selectedSalutation = salutation),
              validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null,
```